ISM330DHCX GDA only set once
I read from the accelelerometer without any problem.
Now I need to read from the gyroscope. I get a first sample, but GDA (gyroscope data available) remains stuck at 0
I configured the register like this:(hexadecimal)
{CTRL9_XL 01, INT1_CTRL 03, INT2_CTRL 06, CTRL1_XL 30, CTRL2_G 32, CTRL3_C 04, CTRL6_C 80, CTRL8_XL 00, MD1_CFG 02, MD2_CFG 02, CTRL9_XL 01}
And await for INT1 interruption (note: I never get INT2 interruption for some reason)
What I expected was after reading the status register, GDA and XLDA would be set.
The actual situation is the first status register read, I have both bits set, and subsequent reads only XLDA is set. If I read gyroscope output registers, values dont change (they never get updated)
